# I cannot link my css and and image to my html

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I tried to link a css to html in laravel and link an image (both css and image are in public folder) but it does not work. I tried using asset and url but it does not work either. I don't understand what is wrong. This is how I wrote the link:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">`

`<img src="/img/logo-kitsune-dojo.jpg" alt="logo kitsune dojo">`

I have already tried asset and url. They don't work. I want mi css and my imagen to link.

Answer (score 0):

use `asset()` function generates a URL

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}">
```

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/logo-kitsune-dojo.jpg') }}" alt="logo kitsune dojo">
```

Answer (score -1):

**You may solve this problem by using asset() helper function**

For css link: If your css exist in public folder folowing this directory you may use this

For Image: If your image exist in public folder folowing this directory you may use this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).